# I have an issue with python lists (program creats unfinished lists inside another list which is not wanted)

Tags: python, list

```
list = []

def lister(*args):
    list.append(args)

while 0 < 1  :  #to create infinite loop
    entry = input("Enter value to add to list")
    
    if entry == "finish()": #it is not a function. it is just a command to end loop. If user writes "finish()" it ends the loop. That is all.
        break
    lister(entry) # this is inside the while loop block. It is after the "if block" because when user enters "finish()" the string "finish()" appends to the list. with this way it doesn't append the string "finish()" which is ok. 

print(list)
```

There is the part i need your help :
When the program runs and enter some information, that creates lists inside a list and then it appends this weird list to the list:

```
[('john',), ('senna',), ('alex',)]
```

every information creates:

```
('john',) # as you see it is a list which have two values. But created by one information
```

So finally, that appends the informations as tuple lists to the container list.
I want to add every entered information to the main list as one index with functions.This is the result i want:

```
['john','senna','alex']
```

Comment: It is a 1 element [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), not an unfinished list.

Comment: Because `*args` will be a tuple…

Comment: ok that is a tuple. But why is there 2 values in it ? Why the comma is in tuple ?

Comment: Because that's what makes it a tuple. Just `('john')` is a string with precedence grouping parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*args` makes the input to be considered as a tuple.

Code can be simplified to:

```
list = []

while True:  # to create infinite loop
    entry = input("Enter value to add to list")
    if entry == "end":
        break
    list.append(entry)

print(list)
```

If you really want to use a function, although not needed, just to learn:

```
# Just the entry, without the *
def add_to_list(entry):
    list.append(entry)
```

Comment: thanks for simplifying. But How can i reach the result i want ? What should i change in my function or shoud i add some more code in my program ?

Comment: @ÖmerCan no need to add more code :) Just run the first code I wrote and enter names and "end" to stop

Answer (score 0):

So function is not needed. If it is: *args is the problem which makes tuples.